# How to display data in a gridview

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

I would like to display data from database to gridview. However, when I make debug, data is read by datareader but it cannot display it into the grid.
Could you help for that issue?
Here is my code.

```
        Dim strSQL_ = "SELECT FDREF, FDESTKCODE, FDESTKEXP, FDEAMOUNT, FDEUNIT, FDEPRICE, " & _
            "FDETOTALPRICE, FMAREF FROM FICHEDETAIL WHERE FMAREF = '" & fmaref3_ & "'"
    Dim dsx1 = New DataSet
    Dim adx1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objCon)
    adx1.Fill(dsx1, "a")
    Dim t1 As DataTable = dsx1.Tables("a")
    mygrid.DataSource = dsx1.Tables("a")

    objCon.Close()

    Dim sqlCmd_ As New SqlCommand(strSQL_, objCon)
    objCon.Open()
    sqlCmd_.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim dreader_ As SqlDataReader
    dreader_ = sqlCmd_.ExecuteReader

    If dreader_.Read Then

        Dim a As Integer
        For a = 0 To GridView6.RowCount - 1
            Dim ref_ As String = dreader_.GetInt32(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDREF")).ToString()
            ref_ = dreader_.GetString(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDESTKCODE")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDESTKCODE", ref_)
            ref_ = dreader_.GetString(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDESTKEXP")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDESTKEXP", ref_)
            ref_ = dreader_.GetDouble(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDEAMOUNT")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDEAMOUNT", ref_)
            ref_ = dreader_.GetString(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDEUNIT")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDEUNIT", ref_)
            ref_ = dreader_.GetDecimal(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDEPRICE")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDEUNIT", ref_)
            ref_ = dreader_.GetDecimal(dreader_.GetOrdinal("FDETOTALPRICE")).ToString()
            GridView6.SetRowCellValue(a, "FDETOTALPRICE", ref_)

        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Usually, the code after `objCon.Close()` is redundant. The `mygrid.DataSource = dsx1.Tables("a")` line is enough to fill the `GridView`.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. I tried lots of things or methods to cope with that. the code after. **objCon.close()** I made comment line, I still cannot display them in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

The code into `For` is never being executed since at this point `GridView6.RowCount = 0`.

I think what you want to do is

```
Dim strSQL = "SELECT FDREF, FDESTKCODE, FDESTKEXP, FDEAMOUNT, FDEUNIT, FDEPRICE, " & _
            "FDETOTALPRICE, FMAREF FROM FICHEDETAIL WHERE FMAREF = '" & fmaref3_ & "'"
    Dim dsx1 = New DataSet
    Dim adx1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objCon)
    adx1.Fill(dsx1, "a")
    Dim t1 As DataTable = dsx1.Tables("a")
    mygrid.DataSource = t1

    objCon.Close()
```

Comment: I'm sorry @equisde. It doesn't work when I use while loop. It still reads the data but cannot be displayed

Comment: @kunzhan  Updated answer. This piece of code should be enough to populate your datagridview

Comment: Actually, I use gridview property in devexpress, not a datagridview @equisde